# Выбор технологии для back-end'a

Tags: c#, wcf

Добрый день!
Пользователь в браузере набирает адрес, скажем, http://site.ru:5000/?id=10
На сервере, где расположен данный сайт, находится серверная часть (программа, служба, сервис?), которая прослушивает порт 5000.
При поступлении запроса от браузера по указанной выше ссылке, эта программа получает значение id (в нашем случае - число 10), считывает определённый графический файл и отдаёт его браузеру как image/jpeg, а браузер его выводит.

Вопрос: какую технологию использовать для серверной части? WCF? Веб-сервисы? Служба Windows?

Comment: ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC не рассматриваете?

Comment: Сам сайт работает на .NET Core 1.0. А обработку фото нужно поручить сервису.
Насколько я понимаю, можно написать службу Windows, которая будет прослушивать определённый порт и выдавать контент на запрос браузера. Это единственный способ или можно, например, с помощью WCF?

Comment: А почему нельзя просто использовать обычное приложение ASP.NET MVC (может быть даже Core, если надо) для обработки этих картинок без сервисов? Принимает запрос, выполняет нужные действия, даёт ответ.

Comment: _А обработку фото нужно поручить сервису_. Если вы это уже решили, то зачем спрашиваете? Тогда у меня встречный вопрос: а почему именно сервису это надо поручить?

Comment: Вадим, вопрос не совсем решён. Я спросил: "Это единственный способ или можно, например, с помощью WCF?" По поводу сервиса. По нескольким причинам. 1. Этот сервис будет находится на отдельном от сайта сервере, с отдельным IP. 2. Этот сервис будут использовать несколько сайтов. 3. Желание попрактиковаться в написании многопоточных сервисов.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC, Nina (https://github.com/jondot/nina), NancyFx (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) как вариант.

Comment: Благодарю всех за помощь! Вопрос решён. Остановился на том, что создаю службу Windows, которая прослушивает необходимый мне порт, и при поступлении запроса обрабатывает его, отдавая нужный контент. Эдакий мини-вебсервер.